# FFmpeg, capturing video is laggy, how to eliminate that?

Tags: ffmpeg

Lets say I dont have a very good computer and my recordings are laggy. Two version I tried:

```
ffmpeg -f dshow -framerate 30 -i video="screen-capture-recorder":audio="virtual-audio-capturer" -vcodec libx264 -crf 0 -preset ultrafast -acodec pcm_s16le output.mkv

ffmpeg -f gdigrab -framerate 30 -i desktop -vcodec libx264 -crf 0 -preset ultrafast -acodec pcm_s16le output.mkv
```

I tried to avoid all compressing stuff, still lagging. Although Im recording 1920x1080 video... I dont care how big the result is. Isnt there an option like "store all frames, and encoding a bit later, I dont care the realtime capturing" ?

Comment: I also tried: ffmpeg -rtbufsize 1500M -f dshow -i video="screen-capture-recorder":audio="virtual-audio-capturer" -vcodec rawvideo -pix_fmt yuv420p -threads 0 -crf 0 -preset ultrafast -tune zerolatency -acodec pcm_s16le output.mkv only a slight better result